# How to add tooltip dialog to items in dijit.form.MultiSelect?

Tags: dojo, multi-select

I am a newbie in Dojo, and I am trying add a tooltip dialog to show more info of an item in dijit.form.MultiSelect but I have no luck so far. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...
1. connect tooltip namespace

```
 dojo.require("dijit.Tooltip");
```

1. get all options from multiselect:

   `var options = dojo.query("#fruit option"); //where 'fruit' - multiselect id`
2. add tooltip for each options

   `dojo.forEach(options, function (option, i) {
       new dijit.Tooltip({
       connectId: [option],
       label: "value <b> bla bla bla </b>  "+ i
       });
      });`

See [working page example](http://pastehtml.com/view/1dwypd2.html)